# ¿Cómo corrijo el procedure para que no permita ingresar como primer registro datos vacios?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedure

E realizado este procedure para insertar valores a la tabla:

```
USE [Calderas]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[ClasificacionProducto]    Script Date: 07/02/2018 06:13:58 p.m. ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ClasificacionProducto](
    [Id_ClaProducto] [nchar](2) NOT NULL,
    [Descripcion] [nvarchar](25) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_ClasificacionProducto] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id_ClaProducto] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY],
UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [Descripcion] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

Al ejecutar el procedure la primera vez exec  usp_NuevaClasificacionProducto '   ', '   ' me registra los datos en blanco, ¿Como puedo corregirlo? y please ayudenme a mejorar el procedure.

```
alter procedure usp_NuevaClasificacionProducto
--Declaro las variables a ingresar a la tabla 
@Codigo nchar(2),
@Descripcion varchar(25) 
as
    begin
    SET NOCOUNT ON
        begin tran e
        begin try
        --Evito duplicidad validando la existencia de la Descripción
                if NOT EXISTS (SELECT Descripcion FROM ClasificacionProducto where Descripcion= @Descripcion)
                begin
        --Al guardar las variables esten en mayúscula y sin espacios
                set @Codigo  = upper(Rtrim(ltrim(@Codigo)))
                set @Descripcion = upper(RTRIM(ltrim(@Descripcion)))
        --Inserto las variables
                insert into ClasificacionProducto(Id_ClaProducto, Descripcion ) 
                values(@Codigo , @Descripcion)
                print 'Datos ingresados' + @Descripcion + @Codigo
                end
        commit tran e
        end try
        begin catch
        --indico que si hay nulos en decripción o código no se inserte
            if @Descripcion is null or @Codigo is null
            print 'Ingresar Descripción o Código ' 
            rollback
        end catch
    SET NOCOUNT OFF
    end
go
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. La cadena vacía es diferente a NULL
2. De acuerdo a la definición de tu tabla los campos no permiten nulos, no es necesario realizar esta validación, el motor simplemente no permitirá que se inserten este tipo de registros.

Por lo que entiendo necesitas realizar la validación de la cadena vacía para obtener el comportamiento que esperas.

```
if @Descripcion = '' or @Codigo is ''
```

Comment: Hola Dennys cambie como me indicaste, pero igual permite para el primer registro insertar valores vacios, la validación solo funciona a partir del segundo registro.

Comment: Claro, lo qué pasa es que la validación nunca se está ejecutando. De acuerdo al flujo del sp, solo se ejecutará cuando ocurra un error en el insert.

Tienes que agregar la condición dentro del try en lugar del catch.

Sobre lo que mencionas del segundo registro es por un error de llave duplicada.